# Is にする always a voluntary action taken by the speaker (or target person)?

Tags: usage

[Source](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-ni-suru-meaning/)

にする is defined as "to decide on" but does it **always** represent a voluntary action taken by the speaker or are there cases when it is not neccesarily up to their decision?

For example,

> 私は明日と来週の火曜日を休みにする。

The English translation from the source is "I'm taking work off tomorrow and next Tuesday." but can it also mean "I have work off tomorrow and next Tuesday." possibly implying the "work off" or break time period was not decided by the speaker (perhaps a manager or whatnot).

---

Bonus question: How would I say "I'm taking work off tomorrow **until** next Tuesday."? My guess is 私は明日**から**来週の火曜日**まで**を休みにする。Does that sound right?

Comment: I don't think we'd normally say `私は明日と来週の火曜日を休みにする。` to mean `I'm taking work off tomorrow and next Tuesday.`　やっぱり, I don't think you should trust JLPT sensei. https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2196/9831

Comment: @Chocolate It seems grammatical at least. I know it's not the actual question, but could you comment on which part is unnatural and what a natural alternative would be please?

Comment: @user3856370 I think we'd normally say 明日と来週の火曜(に/は)休みを取る (or 休みをもらう, or just 休む). 明日と来週の火曜は休みにする sounds to me like a shop owner saying they will not open their shop on those days. 〇曜と〇曜を休みにする sounds like someone who can decide their 定休日 by themselves deciding on which days they'll take days off every week.

Answer (score 3):

> 私は明日と来週の火曜日を休みにする

will always mean "I decided to take tomorrow next Tuesday off."

If you wanted to imply that someone else made that decision, then you would say

> 私は明日と来週の火曜日が休みになった